# Shooting a bullet in front of player C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to Instantiate a 'bullet' in front of the player (the gameobject the script is attached to). I tried (as i saw in other threads), but doesnt work:

```
GameObject  bulletobj = Instantiate (bulletFired, transform.position + transform.forward * 2, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

The problem is that the bullet has a collider that always hit the player because in a certain rotation the bullet spawns behind the player :/, so i need to spawn it in front of him. This is the lines i made to propulse it:

```
var mousePosition = FindObjectOfType<Camera> ().ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Input.mousePosition.z - FindObjectOfType<Camera> ().transform.position.z));

bulletobj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = (mousePosition - transform.position).normalized * bulletSpeed * Time.smoothDeltaTime;
```

Thanks in advance guys :D

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`Physics.IgnoreCollision`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreCollision.html) (actually read the docs for this to save you trouble later on) in order to stop the bullet hitting the player who fires it.

```
GameObject  bulletobj = Instantiate (bulletFired, transform.position + transform.forward * 2, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
Physics.IgnoreCollision(gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>(),
                        bulletobj.GetComponent<BoxCollider>()));
```

This assumes that you have BoxColliders attached to both objects. You will have to change this depending on the type of collider you have attached.

Edit: I feel that I should add, instantiating lots of objects like this is very inefficient. If you are just getting started with unity and just want to get something working then go ahead with this. If you want to do it the proper way then look into [object pooling](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/object-pooling). This is where you instantiate a group of bullets at the start of the game and then reuse them over and over again. This saves unnecessarily assigning lots of memory.

Comment: After putting this - Physics.IgnoreCollision(GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>, bulletobj.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>); - I get "Argument '#1' cannot convert 'method group' expression to type 'UnityEngine.Collider'"

Comment: whoops, typo on my part. Add brackets after the two `GetComponents`. Check my answer now I edited it

Comment: oh yeah i didnt see -_-, it was obvious sorry :D

Comment: The military would sure love reusable ammo! :)

Comment: Did this help? @Ay0m4